# Trying to figure out how to use EasyPHP (MySQL) with Java EE 6

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee-6

I'm trying to figure out how to use MySQL with Java EE 6.  I'd like to work with it locally on my machine so I can get some experience.  Is it possible to do this?  I've seen this [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=404190#mirrors) and I expected it to be like a class or something, but it's a lot more than that and I'm not sure about how to implement it.  Can anyone offer any advice on where to get started?  I did find one article that wasn't as detailed as I'd hoped, but it was from 2004 anyways, so it's no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm not familiar with EasyPHP: is it some kind of bundled package?  Are you just asking for how to connect to a MySQL database from Java?

Comment: @DanielPryden - EasyPHP is a way of running MySQL/Apache on Windows.  I have full access to MySQL, I just need to know how to connect Java to it like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) trail in the official Java documentation describes how you access databases from Java.  The [JDBC Basics Getting Started page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html) says that the tutorial has been tested with MySQL.

You will need to install the MySQL JDBC driver (I presume that's what you've linked to above) and have it on your classpath in order for the database connection to work.  But other than having it on your classpath, you shouldn't need to interact with any MySQL-specific classes from your code.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are using EasyPHP to stand up a MySQL instance on Windows? Seems like a little bit of overkill but in any case here is what you can do:

1. Download and install [Jboss 7](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) (Full profile).
2. Run JBoss (/bin/standalone.bat>
3. Download [MySQL connector for Java](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
4. Unzip, then copy the MySQL connector Jar to /standalone/deployments
5. Login to JBoss admin console (http://localhost:8080)
6. Browse to Connector/Datasources and define a new datasource pointing to your MySQL DB

Thats it for setting up a server environment. Now you can do all your JEE6 goodness in your favorite IDE and deploy the code to your Jboss server. Or you can skip all that and use the baked in goodies in NetBeans. A good tutorial can be followed [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html).